# How to manually disambiguate partial specializations when using C++20 concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

If I define two concepts and have partial specializations of a class for each one, then clearly if I have a type that satisfies both, I have an ambiguity:

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
concept HasBar = requires {
   typename T::Bar;
};

template <typename T>
concept HasBaz = requires {
   typename T::Baz;
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo;

template <typename T> requires(HasBar<T>)
struct Foo<T> {
    static void frobnicate() {
        fprintf(stderr, "HasBar!\n");
    }
};

template <typename T> requires(HasBaz<T>)
struct Foo<T> {
    static void frobnicate() {
        fprintf(stderr, "HasBaz!\n");
    }
};

int main() {
   struct MyFoo {
      using Bar = int;
      using Baz = float;
   };
   
   Foo<MyFoo>::frobnicate();
}
```

Yields:

```
<source>:42:15: error: ambiguous partial specializations of 'Foo<MyFoo>'
   42 |    Foo<MyFoo> foo;
      |               ^
<source>:23:8: note: partial specialization matches [with T = MyFoo]
   23 | struct Foo<T> {
      |        ^
<source>:30:8: note: partial specialization matches [with T = MyFoo]
   30 | struct Foo<T> {
      |        ^
```

If I remove the `Baz` type from `Foo` then all goes according to plan and it prints `HasBar!`

When the specialization is ambiguous like this, I'd like to manually specify a priority.  I thought I could do it with a tower of tag types, with lower values representing higher priorities:

```
#include <cstdio>

template <int N>
struct Priority : Priority<N-1> {};

template <>
struct Priority<0> {};

template <typename T>
concept HasBar = requires {
   typename T::Bar;
};

template <typename T>
concept HasBaz = requires {
   typename T::Baz;
};

template <typename T, typename Enabled = void>
struct Foo;

template <typename T> requires(HasBar<T>)
struct Foo<T, Priority<1>> {
    static void frobnicate() {
        fprintf(stderr, "HasBar!\n");
    }
};

template <typename T> requires(HasBaz<T>)
struct Foo<T, Priority<0>> {
    static void frobnicate() {
        fprintf(stderr, "HasBaz!\n");
    }
};

int main() {
   struct MyFoo {
      using Bar = int;
      using Baz = float;
   };
   
   Foo<MyFoo>::frobnicate();
}
```

But that seems to just exclude the two partial specializations entirely:

```
<source>:42:4: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Foo<MyFoo>'
   42 |    Foo<MyFoo>::frobnicate();
```

How should one do this in the new C++20 concepts world?

Answer (score 2):

If having `Bar` should have precedence in this case, you could require that the specialization for `HasBaz<T>` does not also have `Bar`:

```cpp
template <typename T> requires(HasBaz<T> && !HasBar<T>)
//                                          ^^^^^^^^^^
struct Foo<T> {
    static void frobnicate() {
        fprintf(stderr, "HasBaz!\n");
    }
};
```

Output:

```
HasBar!
```

---

If you remove `Bar` from `MyFoo`:

```cpp
int main() {
   struct MyFoo {
      //using Bar = int;
      using Baz = float;
   };
   
   Foo<MyFoo>::frobnicate();
}
```

Output:

```
HasBaz!
```

Comment: Yeah that might be what I do in this case, clearly that doesn't generalize as the number of concepts grows by even a couple though.

Comment: @gct No, that may be true if you have many many specializations.

Answer (score 0):

You might use priority with function overload though:

```
template <typename T>
requires(HasBar<T>)
void frobnicate(Priority<1>) { fprintf(stderr, "HasBar!\n"); }

template <typename T>
requires(HasBaz<T>)
void frobnicate(Priority<0>) { fprintf(stderr, "HasBaz!\n"); }

template <typename T>
void frobnicate() { frobnicate<T>(Priority<1>{}); }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PaWqqGofP)

Comment: Yeah in this case I need it to resolve the class for the particular type though since I'm implementing a way of statically resolving adapters for types.